# How to setup certificate for Client in Fellow-Oak Dicom?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, dicom, fo-dicom

Deak folks, I'm trying to setup a Dicom Client using the Fellow Oak Dicom library. I succesfully do all the queries, using the DicomClient class, as indicated in their github page https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom .

However, how can I specify a certificate to use for authenticating my client?

I found that this is how you usually do in C#, https://www.medo64.com/2014/09/client-authenticated-tls-in-c/
and I see that this is exactly what the Fo-Dicom library is doing. I can't find a way to specify my certificate though.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I solved it by overriding the DesktopNetworkStream class where I just replaced, in the main constructor,

```
ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(host)
```

with

```
var trust = new X509Certificate2("serverCert.p12","myPwd");
var key = new X509Certificate2("clientCert.p12","myPwd");
var clientCertificateCollection = new X509CertificateCollection(new X509Certificate[] { trust,key });

ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(host, clientCertificateCollection, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
```

and I call it, instead of

```
client.Send(serverIp, serverPort, false, callingAET, calledAET);
```

with

```
var _networkStream = new DesktopNetworkStream(serverIp, serverPort, true, true, true);
client.Send(_networkStream, callingAET, calledAET, 5000);
```